# Android Notifications custom view and button press

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have notification with custom view that contains button. When user press the button in notification it should get some Toast message. However Toast never shows up because `onReceive` is never called. What I'm doing wrong?

```
        int icon = R.drawable.play;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);

    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),R.layout.notification);
    PendingIntent listenerIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, AudioControlListener.class), 0);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.background, listenerIntent);

    notification.contentView = notificationView;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    startForeground(1, notification);
```

my broadcast receiver class

```
 public static class AudioControlListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to show the toast in the phone's home page?

Comment: That doesn't care. I just want that trigger `onReceive` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `PendingIntent.getService()` with an `Intent` that has a `BroadcastReceiver` target. You need to use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` instead. And make sure your Receiver is registered in the manifest.